# Faking screen resolution given to website

Tags: display, resolution, spoofing

I would like to ask you how to fake screen resolution given to web page. I've just kept trying googling it for 20 minutes to no avail. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try googling for "User Agent Change".  It would help if you specify the browser that you are using.

Comment: He is asking about screen resolution. For example 1024x768. User Agent Change just fakes what user agent your browser is using.

Comment: True, however the options to change the reported screen resolution are usually in the same place as the options to change the User Agent.  Searching for "User Agent" will usually lead to the right place.

Answer (score 6):

In Firefox you can access it through

```
Tools → Web Developer → Responsive Design View
```

You can choose a pre defined screen size, or input your own.

Comment: Is there an api for this option ? For enabling it through js code ?

Answer (score 5):

In google chrome, you can do this in the developer tools.

1. Go to View->Developer->Developer Tools
2. Click on the settings button in the lower right corner.
3. Select Overrides from the settings

Here you can change the reported screen resolution among other setting.

Answer (score 4):

In Internet Explorer you can access the Developer tools in these ways:

> `Hit the F12 key`

Or

> `Tools > Developer Tools`

Once you are in the Developer Tools sections:

> `Click Tools > Resize`

This allows you to pick the resolution you want to display as.